# How to filter all non-numeric characters ,and digits to make from string to numbers

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4

I want to activate a function by following these steps:

1.First filter out all non-numeric characters.

2.Calculate any linear function on these numbers.

3.Calculate the product of each results and return an answer.

ex:

```
>>print(digit_com_mul("8?97D4b"))

   36
```

This is the function I tried to perform but I do not understand how after the filter to turn the string into numbers

```
def digit_complete_mul(data):
     return reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,map(lambda x: 10-x,int(filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),data))))
```

Comment: This one-liner is very clever. You should make your code simpler if you want anyone to read it.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I don't get how the OP is using `reduce` in Python3 without `functools`... maybe they imported it anonymously?

Comment: of course I imported the reduce from functools...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a string (`s`) and a linear function (`f`), the following works:

```
def func(s, f):
    l = (f(int(c)) for c in s if c.isdigit())
    p = 1
    for i in l:
        p *= i
    return p
```

---

You could also use the `functools.reduce` approach:

```
def func(s, f):
    l = (f(int(c)) for c in s if c.isdigit())
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y : x*y, l)
```

*(you could throw that first line into the second if you wanted, but its slightly unnecessary)*

---

And both give the expected output:

```
>>> func('a1b2cd3e', lambda x: x+1)
24
>>> 2 * 3 * 4 #<-- same calc.
24
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
digits = (int(c) for c in input_string if c.isdigit())
values_of_f = map(f, digits)
product = functools.reduce(lambda acc, x: acc * x, values_of_f)
```

Write down first, inline later (if ever).

Answer (score 0):

So i find a way .

just in the linear function change the character to int:

```
from functools import reduce

def digit_complete_mul(data):
    return reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,map(lambda x: 10-int(x),filter(lambda x:x.isdigit(),data)))
```